# Socket.io alternative for modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Are there custom builds of [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) or alternative libraries with the same functionality 
for modern browsers only (Websockets only) without all the drag code and flash to support old browsers?

Answer (score 1):

There's **SockJS** (http://sockjs.org) that builds upon WebSockets without all the fallback technologies, but the library is different from Socket.io.

I haven't heard of custom builds.